# Call an executable from C code having same address space

Tags: c, exec

From code "A", I want to call an executable "B" having some arguments.
I'm passing as an argument, an address belonging to code "A" which I need in "B".

I considered doing execl but the new process image replaces the old process image and thus the address that I passed has no significance in "B"'s context.

Is there any other way of achieving this?
I considered fork but "B" is a different executable altogether, so creating a child process won't help.

Comment: Why can't you `fork` and then `exec` in there? I don't understand your last statement.

Comment: So you're saying fork a child and then call exec on it? Will the parent's addresses still be meaningful? I thought execl gets a new address space and so whatever I pass it would be irrelevant.

Comment: After the `fork`, the address in A is unrelated to the same address in B. You need to use [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#Support_on_Unix-like_systems).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Can't use fork. Is shared memory the only other alternative?

Comment: An executable in the same address space as some other executable is basically what a shared library is.

Comment: Got my way around it using fork+exec. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you need to pass?